"not in" subquery in snowflake unavailable
i'm trying to construct a case statement that flags if the values are not in the values in a table.
case when lower(last_name_part2) not in (select lower(last_name) from scratch.white_surnames) then 1 else 0 end as nonwhite_names
but snowflake says

'Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated'

This method works for "in" but not "not in." what is the proper syntax for doing this case statement in snowflake or is it just not possible? is there another way?
thanks
i tried "not in" but got the "unsupported" error

are you sure both last_name_part2 and last_name are the same datatype or at least  compatible datatype?

yes they are both string

how abut using exists :
select case when exists (select 1 FROM from scratch.white_surnames WHERE lower(last_name_part2) = lower(last_name)) then 0 else 1 end as nonwhite_names
from table_name


Hi I would suggest trying the below
not (case when lower(last_name_part2) in (select lower(last_name) from scratch.white_surnames)) then 0 else 1 end as nonwhite_names
